# Multiple ViewModels/Single View with MVC Contrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvccontrib

First of all, this is not a new question.  My question is actually a follow up question to one of the answers provided by **gWiz**.  The link to his post/answer is here:

[Multiple models sent to a single view instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003801/multiple-models-sent-to-a-single-view-instance/2009100#2009100)

> Another way to do this would be not to strongly-type the view and
> master pages in the page directive, but instead make use of the
> generic type-based ViewData extensions from MVC Contrib. These
> extensions basically use the fully-qualified type name as the ViewData
> dictionary key. Effectively, the typing benefits are the same as the
> strongly-typed page approach, with less class overhead in terms of the
> number of view model classes required. Then in your actions you do
>
> `ViewData.Add<Car>(car); ViewData.Add<LayoutAData>(layoutAData);`
>
> and in the views you do
>
> `<%= ViewData.Get<Car>().Color %>`
>
> and in the master page you do
>
> `<%= ViewData.Get<LayoutAData>().Username %>`
>
> You could cache these Get<> calls inline in the views to mitigate the
> cost of casting multiple times.

My question is specifically about the last comment: How would one go about "caching" the get calls in the View?  Doesn't the view get destroyed and created each time?

I did try searching for examples but maybe I wasn't asking the right question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he might be saying is that instead of

```
<%= ViewData.Get<Car>().Color %>
<%= ViewData.Get<Car>().Make %>
```

You assign it to a variable and use the variable later

```
<% var car = ViewData.Get<Car>(); %>

<%= car.Color %>
<%= car.Make %>
```